# How to know when USB-C is disconnected without measuring current?

Tags: circuit-design, usb-c

I need an alarm to go off when a USB-C connector is disconnected from a phone. Need to do this without measuring current or voltage. So basically integrating it another way into hardware circuit outside the phone or something along the lines. Any information will help. I already tried using a voltage comparator and it didn't work.

Comment: Why can't you measure current?

Comment: trying to work around that. @Hearth

Comment: What went wrong with your voltage comparator approach?

Comment: If you can't measure current or voltage, you can't measure *anything* about the electrical circuitry. So, this is impossible. Please make more clear what you actually can and cannot do, and *why*.

Comment: Exactly i need another approach that doesn't involve measuring current or voltage. @MarcusMüller

Comment: @aamir The measurable states of a circuit encompass voltages and currents. If you can't measure them, what **can** you measure? And to better understand the problem, **why** do you think you can't measure them?

Comment: there's no other option. When you observe an electrical circuit, the **only** things that you can observe are current and voltage. please edit your question to clarify what I've asked for.

Comment: the other option is a mechanical sensor and that would be off topic here

Comment: realizing this is a pure X/Y problem (should be: how do I fix my voltage measurement setup? is: how do I measure without measuring?) , I'm voting to close this as unclear. aamir, feel free to ask a new question that describes your specific problems you had implementing this voltage comparator approach. It's pretty reasonable.

Comment: Insufficient info in the question. Is the alarm supposed to be in the phone or it is external? Is the phone acting as USB host or device? Is the phone charging or is it supplying USB power?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect an event without measuring something. Connection over Type-C is determined by **voltage level** on the special CC pin. One end of CC wire (across a C-C cable) will be connected to "provider" with a pull-up resistor. The other end ("consumer") will have 5.1k pull down. Depending on which side do you plan an alarm, a **voltage** comparator is needed. If it is on "provider" side, high voltage (above 2V) on CC wire will indicate disconnect. If an alarm is needed on "consumer" side, "zero voltage" (below 0.4V) will indicate the disconnect. A smartphone will know the disconnect through its connection manager software. Intelligent charging host can do the same. If your charger has not much intelligence, a simple voltage comparator will be required.

More, a normal Type-C provider will drop charging voltage (VBUS) if it senses the disconnect on CC pin, which should be really easy to detect.